# Updating the status on react in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, firebase-storage

How did useEffect update the list of files in the application when adding a new file to the firebase storage?

```
export const ModalFileInfo: FC<IModalFileInfo> = ({ id, openInfo }) => {
  const [ uploadFiles, setUploadFiles ] = useState<any>(null);
  const [ filesList, setFilesList ] = useState<StorageReference[]>([]);

  const refFile = useRef<any>(null);

  const listRef = ref(storage, `${id}/`);

  const upload = () => {
      for(let i = 0; i < uploadFiles.length; i++) {
        let file = uploadFiles[i];
        const filesRef = ref(storage, `${id}/${file.name}`)
        uploadBytes(filesRef, file)
      }
      alert('Файлы загружены')
      refFile.current.value = null;
      setUploadFiles(null)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    listAll(listRef).then((res) => {
      setFilesList(res.items);
    })
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={styles.Main}>
      <div className={styles.MainOverlay}></div>
      <div className={styles.MainWrapper}>
        <AiOutlineCloseCircle className={styles.MainWrapperClose} onClick={() => openInfo(false)}/>
        <h1 className={styles.MainWrapperTitle}>
          Файлы
        </h1>
        <div className={styles.MainWrapperUpload}>
          <input multiple ref={refFile} type="file"  onChange={e => setUploadFiles(e.target.files)}/>
          <button disabled={uploadFiles === null} className={styles.MainWrapperUploadAdd} onClick={upload}>Загрузить</button>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.MainWrapperInfo}>
          <div className={styles.MainWrapperInfoFeature}>
            <div>Название</div>
            <div>Тип файла</div>
            <div>Размер</div>
          </div>
          <div>
            {filesList.map(item => (
                <FileItem key={item.name} name={item.name} idTask={id}/>
              ))}
          </div>
          <div className={styles.MainWrapperInfoList}>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I tried to add different dependencies, added memoization, but useEffect either does not see the changes or requests data indefinitely